# OnPaint event is slow and throws "shadows"

Tags: c#, image, winforms, draw, onpaint

I'm currently trying to draw some sprites on my WinForms with the OnPaint Event. I used a PictureBox before and it worked but because I could not handle the overlapping of multiple PictureBoxes I switched to the OnPaint Event. I looked around the Internet but could not find an answer for my problem.

all sprites I have are embedded resources in my projects. I put them in a List of type 'image' and loop over them when pressing a certain button (KeyEvent).

I have a Timer_Tick Event that looks like this:

```
     private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
```

My OnPaint method is like this:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;

            if (SPRITE_POS == 0)
            DrawSprite(spriteList[SPRITE_POS]);

            if (SPRITE_POS != spriteList.Count - 1)
            SPRITE_POS++;
    }
```

And the DrawSprite Method:

```
    private void DrawSprite(Image img)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img);
        bitmap.SetResolution(60, 60);
        PEA.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, P1_X, P1_Y);
    }
```

For somehow reason I get this results for fast keypresses (Tried this with images from Sub-Zero from MK):

[image: Shadow]

Without Double Buffering it is flickering. With Double Buffering I'm getting this result above. It throws 'shadows'. Is it possible to avoid this easily? The last sprite is still getting displayed for a moment when the new sprite is already drawn on the form.

Thank you so much!

Comment: have you try ```e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);``` before drawing anything?

Comment: Yes. I get the same result. I even tried to slow down the Timer_Tick event but always the same result

Comment: Setting DoubleBuffered to true in OnPaint() is not correct, belongs in the constructor.

Comment: what about clear backbuffer ? i can't see it in your sample code.

Comment: You have `PEA.Graphics`, but "PEA" was not passed to the `DrawSprite()` method...this is almost certainly a bad thing.  Did you call `CreateGraphics()` at a previous point and then store it at class level?...

Comment: I put DoubleBuffered now into the constructor. Does not help. How do ich clear the backbuffer? PEA ist just the PaintEvent which I store in a globale variable to pass it to external methods. Because I'm calling external methods in the Event

Comment: "How do ich clear...?"  When you OVERRIDE the OnPaint() method, you need to call `base.OnPaint(e);`.  This should clear the background.  Is that being called?  See [Overriding the OnPaint Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/overriding-the-onpaint-method).

Comment: Does not help :/ Still the same result. I called it at the beginning of the OnPaint Event and tried the Clear method. Still the same result

Comment: Not sure where to go from here.  I'd pass that "e.Graphics" from the Paint() event to the other methods just to eliminate that as a possibility.

Comment: Did help to put it into the method! Thanks a lot!